# SSAS Cube Partition/s partially process

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

I have a cube with multiple measure groups each with 20+ partitions.  When I do a full process of the cube, 1-3 partitions of a particular measure group dont fully process, as in, some data is available, whilst the majority is not.  Processing the individual partitions/s in question then makes all the data available.

Any thoughts anyone?  I have never seen this issue before.

Comment: Do you see any errors or warning when doing the full process?

Comment: None, it was a full process, not errors reported, and no error handling.